# Cross-Validation on Long form data for classification model

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, cross-validation, model

I am working on a model to predict the risk of Type 2 Diabetes. The data is indexed on each A1c test. I look forward 2 years from the test to see if there is the diagnosis of T2 Diabetes. So, the data is in longform - there are multiple observations for each member + test combination. ie like this (simplified)

```
Name  A1c  Event
Scott 5.6   0
Scott 5.7   0
Scott 5.4   0
John  5.3   0 
John  5.8   1
```

There are also a slew of other predictor variables, including a time variable.

**My question is, when doing a train/test split must each member be in ONLY train OR test?** What if one observation for Scott is in the test and the other two are in the train?

Further, if I choose to cross-validate (Say, bootstrap with replacement) do I need to put a similar constraint on the holdout group as above with the train/test?

Please let me know if I can provide more info to help answer the question.